# Static file requests don't raise application_error event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, application-error

in my Asp.Net MVC project I'm cathing Http FileNotFound Exceptions (for a missing image) and then redirect request to a default image like below

```
  protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Path.StartsWith("/images/profile"))
        {

            Response.Redirect("/images/profile/default.jpg", true);
            return;
        }
    }
```

It is working in development envirement when I am debugging my website. But when I deploy it to production server that runs IIS 7.5 This code isn't working, request to a image file does not trigger the Application_Error event. Is there any configuration on IIS? I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure IIS to run all requests through ASP.Net.

Add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to `<system.webServer>` in Web.config.

---

Also, you should add a route for this instead of handling the `Error` event.

Comment: +1 This question and your answer made me realize I'd been making a silly assumption about 404 errors somehow being different from other ones as far as how IIS handled them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> in my system.webServer . There must be an other configuration. what you mean add a route for this.

Comment: Great answer, so we are going to send all of our static file requests all the way through the asp.net pipeline on every request just so we can handle the 404 requests in `Application_Error`. Let's assume we are logical people, then what do we do?